# Mega menu css error

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My mega menu behaves correctly for the half of the menu. The other half gets pushed to the right too much. Is there a CSS expert here that knows why? I'm using bootstrap in my project.

The css isnt hardcoded , my code is from firebug

http://jsfiddle.net/jdc1dmvn/3/

this is the real code for those that understand asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_OnItemBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul id="mega-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav mega-menu">
            <li><a href="<%: FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Default") %>">Hem</a></li>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ParentCatName") %></a>
            <asp:Repeater ID="ParentCatRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ChildRepeater_OnItemBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href="<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Category", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryID")) %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryName") %></a>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <%-- <asp:HyperLink ID="Linkproduct" NavigateUrl="" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %></asp:HyperLink>--%>
                                    <a href="<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/Product", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID")) %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %></a>

                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't hardcode it. But the problem lies with bootstrap.

If you remove `position: relative` from this css line, it will work.

```
.nav>li {  //bootstrap.min.css : line 5
position: relative;
display: block;
}
```

Or you can add this to your own css file (if it's loaded after bootstrap) else you may need to use `!important`

```
.nav > li{
    position:static;
}
```

Comment: can you overwrite this in yor own css file or do i have to edit the real bootstrap css file? @TeeDeJee

Comment: See my edit. It is possible if you set `position` to `static`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have the `style=` values hardcoded in your html.

Your HTML:

```
<li class="dc-mega-li"><a href="#" class="dc-mega">Penslar<span class="dc-mega-icon"></span></a>

    <div class="sub-container mega" style="left: 311px; margin-left: -141px; top: 50px; z-index: 1000;">
```

Should be:

```
<li class="dc-mega-li"><a href="#" class="dc-mega">Penslar<span class="dc-mega-icon"></span></a>

    <div class="sub-container mega">
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/jdc1dmvn/11/

A general rule of thumb is avoid the style attribute at all costs.

Comment: thats the code i copied from Firebug my real one is a repeater with asp.net

Comment: ... You should copy from source not firebug. Anyway its working.

Comment: the mega-menu plugin is writing that, the only thing i coded is <ul id="mega-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav mega-menu">

Answer (score 0):

in your css u need to change left css property because in half menu you got `left: 0;` and in second half more then 300px; plesse check .sub-container and inline styles

Comment: the megamenu plugin is writing ths css is just write <ul id="mega-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav mega-menu">